# All Index recommendations are automatically reverted

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have a serverless SQL Server Database deployed in Azure and we get a lot if Index recommendations. All of them are with `High` estimated impact but all of them get reverted.

Another strange this is that `DTU regression (overall)`, `DTU regression (affected queries)`, `Queries with improved performance` and `Queries with regressed performance` in the validation report are all zeroes for all recommendations (over 20 and counting).

Is it normal that none are applied after the validation stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure SQL Database has an intelligent automatic tuning mechanism that takes care of your indexes. If you cannot identify and monitor your indexes, you can let the Azure SQL database do index management for you, tune your database, and ensure that your data structures dynamically adapt to your workload.

Azure SQL Database monitors the query performance after an index is created using automatic tuning. The automatic indexing uses data from the missing index DMV, and it monitors the recommendation over time using the query store. If it does not detect any performance improvement, it automatically reverts the recommendations.Validation process an take up to 72 hours.

In addition, in case the index fails or is postponed due to high CPU, IO, low Storage – once the resource utilization is normal and the automatic tuning believes the index would be beneficial, the process (creation of index) will start again.

This is how it works.

Comment: Thanks, @Alberto Morillo. This much I know but I was wondering why there is no index applied at all. I have ran queries to identify possible missing indexes and they show the same that Azure Recommendations picks. It is very strange that all the parameters in the validation report show zeroes - there is no way that the all of the suggested indexes have absolutely zero impact.

Comment: If during the validation Azure determines there are no significant performance gains it will rollback them. My suggestion is to examine query plans that are missing indexes and add them or modify existing indexes to satisfy those query plans needs. Automatic Tuning is for users that do not know how to optimize queries. Automatic Tuning won't tell you that modifying and existing index is better than creating a new one.